# clearInterval is not stopping time consistenly

Tags: javascript, html, clearinterval

I'm creating a simple game of boggle that limits the user to 30 seconds. After that time, the game ends and the results are displayed. The problem is SOMETIMES everything works fine and the "timer" html shows Times Up. Other times, the countdown starts counting backward. My interval id variable is global and initially set to null. I'm not sure what's going on.

```js
function words(x)
{
 switch (x)
 {
 case 1:
  var word = new Array("balte","table","hat","tab","belt","lab","eat","tea","ate","tale","bale","let","bet","teal","late","beat");
  break;  
 case 2:
  var word = new Array("atwre","water","wet","wear","tear","war","ret","rate","eat","ate","tea","awe","raw","rat","wart","art","tar");
  break;
 case 3:
  var word = new Array("dclaen","can","cane","and","clan","lane","lean","lend","land","den","dean","dance","lance","clean","deal","ale","dale","candle","clad");
  break;
 case 4:
  var word = new Array("aepinlar","air","airplane","plane","plan","lane","lean","pane","ear","near","nap","nape","lair","pen","pan","ape","leap","ale","peal","nap","rap","par", "pare", "pale", "are", "rail", "ail", "pail", "nail", "air", "pair", "ran", "pin", "pine", "line", "nip", "rip", "ripe", "lip", "earn", "learn", "ire");
  break;
 case 5:
  var word = new Array("redykboa","keyboard","key","board","bored","bore","bark","dark","dork","oar","boar","ark","dare","bare","are","red","rod","road","bode","rode","ode","bread", "read", "bead", "bred", "break", "drey", "day", "boy", "broke", "rake", "bake", "ear", "dear", "bear", "dye", "dyer", "doer", "oak", "boa", "doe", "okay","dab", "bade", "ade", "drake", "bard", "yard", "year", "beak", "beard", "bad", "bed", "bay");
  break;
            
    case 6:
  var word = new Array("evtsaedri","advertise","side","eat","sad","sat","rat","rate","vet","advise","read","rest","vest","serve","served","aside","east","tread","dear","deer","tear","trade","starve","steer","stare","veer","seat","seed","tree","drives","strive");
  break;
 case 7:
  var word = new Array("rcseanbh","branches","bra","she","ran","bran","car","cab","race","ranch","share","bench","bar","char","can","crane","ban","hear","hare");
  break;
 case 8:
  var word = new Array("vradntseue","adventures","vent","dent","stun","dust","rust","vase","sure","ensure","star","vend","dare","tar","starve","trade","sad","eat veer","tear","seat","seed","sand","tree","rest");
  break;
 case 9:
  var word = new Array("wokcnalgede","acknowledge","and","land","wand","wage","ledge","led","lead","lend","leg","gown","know","now","no","lean","wean","week","wed","lack","leak","deal","deck","knew","kneel");
  break;
 case 10:
  var word = new Array("muprith","triumph","hit","hurt","pit","trim","rum","rump","tip","thump","put","rim","him","hum","hip","rut");
  break;
 }    
 return word;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Greg's Gambits | Greg's Game of Boggle</title>
 <link href="greg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gregBoggle2.js"></script>
    <script>
        
        compWords = new Array(); notAword = new Array();
        playWords = new Array();
        var play = ""; /*var today;*/ var count = 30;
        var score = 0; var interval = null; 
        var quit = false;
        
        function start()
        {
            /*var start = new Date();
            today = start.getTime();*/
            timeIt();
            boggle();
        }
        function displayLetters()
        {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) +1;
            compWords = words(num);
            yourWord = compWords[0];
            document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML = yourWord;
        }  
        function timeIt()
        {
            interval = window.setInterval("countdown()",1000);
        }
        function countdown()
        {
            count--;
        if (count == 0)
            {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                interval = null;
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time's Up";
                var btn =document.getElementById("start");
                btn.disabled = true;
                quit = true;
                checkWin();
                return;
            }
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
        }
        
        function boggle()
        {
            play = document.getElementById("words").value;
            if (!quit)
            {
                playWords.push(play);
                displayEntries();
                document.getElementById("words").value = "";
                document.getElementById("words").focus();
            } 
            else    
            {
                document.getElementById("words").value = "";
                document.getElementById("words").focus();
                checkWin();
            }    
                    
        }
        function displayEntries()
        {
            document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML = playWords.toString();
                
        }
        
        /*function toMinutesAndSeconds(millis)
        {
            var minutes = Math.floor(millis/60000);
            var seconds = ((millis%60000)/1000).toFixed(0);
            
            return minutes + ":" + ((seconds < 10 ? '0' : "")+ seconds);
        }*/
        function checkWin()
        {
            // check winning score and list bad words
            var complgth = compWords.length;
            var playlgth = (playWords.length);
            var flag; var timePlayed;
            /*var endTime = new Date().getTime();
            var diff = endTime - today;
            timePlayed = toMinutesAndSeconds(diff);*/
            for (var i = 0; i < playlgth; i++)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    for (var k = 0; k < complgth; k++)
                        {
                             if (playWords[i] == compWords[k])
                                 {
                                     score= score + 1;
                                     flag = 1;
                                 }
                        }
                    
                    if (flag == 0)
                        notAword.push(playWords[i]);
                }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ("Your score is " +
                score + ". The following entries " + "are not valid words: <br />" +
                notAword.toString());
            /*document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ("Your time: " + timePlayed);*/

        }    
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <img src="images/superhero.jpg" width="120" height="120" class="floatleft" />
    <h1 align="center"><em>Greg's Game of Boggle</em></h1>
    <div style = "clear:both;"></div>
    <div id = "nav">
        <p><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href = "greg.html">About</a>
        <a href = "play_games.html">Play a Game</a>
        <a href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
        <a href = "contact.html">Contact Us</a></p>            
    </div>
<div id="content">
    <p>The object of the game is to create as many words as
    you can. Please click the Display letters button and your letters will
    be shown below. You have 10 possible letter combinations and 30 seconds. When you are ready to begin, enter the word then click the Submit Word button. The timer will start after first entered word.</p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Display letters" onclick="displayLetters();" /><br/>
        <input type="text" id="words">
        <input type="button" id="start" value="Submit Word" onclick="start();" />
    </p>
    
    <h2><br /><br />Letters you can use:<br /><div id="letters">&nbsp;</div><br /></h2>
    <h2>Your words so far: <br /><div id="entries">&nbsp;</div><br /></h2>
    <h2>Results:<br /><div id="result">&nbsp;</div></h2> 
    <h2>Timer: <br /><div id="timer">&nbsp;</div></h2>
</div>
<div id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2013 Greg's Gambits<br />
<a href="mailto:foulksy@gmail.com">foulksy@gmail.com</a>
</div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you submit a word, you call your start() function which calls timeIt(). Your solution works if you only submit one word, but if you submit multiple, you'll run into the issue where you see a negative timer.

I believe you have to clear the previous setInterval before creating a new one and storing it on your interval variable:

```
    function timeIt()
    {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        interval = window.setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: that or simply don't attach if the interval is set already :)

Answer (score -1):

You should replace this line

```
interval = window.setInterval("countdown()",1000);
```

with the following

```
interval = window.setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

You need to pass a function as the first parameter which can be called by the timer. You pass a string, which can't be called.

[More information here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because, not only is what it states wrong (although, as @Ry said, not recommended), it does not answer the question being asked.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is why it's failing, but setInterval takes a function as its first argument, not a string. It should be `setInterval(countdown, 1000)` not `setInterval("countdown()", 1000)`.

Comment: It can actually take either, though the string version should never be used (it’s like `eval`).

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because, not only is what it states wrong (although, as @Ry said, not recommended), it does not answer the question being asked.